# Switching between client threads in a Java server

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I am working on a project trying to make several people be able to control a robot arm. For this they have to connect to a Java server that then sends the commands to a robot screen for video conferencing.
I am trying to have a thread for each client and then I want to be able to switch between the different clients based on sound, because I want the speaker to be able to control the robot.
The clients all provide positional data and the level of sound taken by the kinect, and sent to the server in the form of a string.
I am having problems with performing the switch. Currently they seem to be switching back and forth and it makes the robot go haywire.

**Is there a good way of comparing the threads to each other, find the appropriate one, switch to that, all the while checking the other threads to see if or when they become the most appropriate one? While also checking in case other clients try to connect to the server?**

Thank you for your help.

I also include my code in case you want to look through it and get a better idea.

This is the server class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable {
    protected int       serverPort  = 8888;
    protected ServerSocket  serverSocket    = null;
    protected boolean   isStopped       = false;
    protected Thread        runningThread   = null;
    protected Thread        clientThread    = null;
    protected Thread        threadThread    = null;
    private Hashtable<Long, WorkerRunnable> Users = new Hashtable<Long, WorkerRunnable>();
    private ArrayList<Thread> ClientThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    private WorkerRunnable  client          = null;
    private ThreadHandler   threadHandler   = null;
    private int             sound_max       = 0;
    private boolean         once            = true;

    public MultiThreadedServer (int port) {
         this.serverPort = port;
    }

    public void run() {
    synchronized(this) {
        this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }
    openServerSocket();
    threadHandler = new ThreadHandler();
    while( !isStopped() ) {
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost());
            clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();          // Connect to clients
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            if( isStopped() ) {
                System.out.println("Server Stopped");
                return;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Error accepting client connection", e);
        }

        client = new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket, "Multithreaded Server");//Class does client work
        clientThread = new Thread(client);          // Make a thread for each client
        clientThread.start();                       // start thread

        threadHandler.setUp(client, clientThread);  // Set up the thread handler
        if ( once == true) {                        // make sure the threadHandler thread is only created once
            threadThread = new Thread(threadHandler);
            threadThread.start();
            once = false;
        }   
    }
    System.out.println("Server Stopped");
}

/**
 * Check if the socket is stopped
 * @return true if the socket is stopped
 */
private synchronized boolean isStopped() {
    return this.isStopped;
}

/**
 * Stop and close the socket
 */
public synchronized void stop() {
    this.isStopped = true;
    try {
        this.serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
    }
}

    /**
     * Open server socket
     */
    private void openServerSocket() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 8888", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Worker class, that handles the data from the clients:

```
import gnu.io.NoSuchPortException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {

    protected Socket clientSocket   = null;
    protected String serverText     = null;
    private BufferedReader inFromClient;
    private DataOutputStream outToClient;
    private int[] currentPos = new int[6];
    private boolean connected = false;
    static TwoWaySerialComm serialCom = null;
    static MultiServoState mState;
    static int sound_average;
    int[] degrees = new int[7];
    int count = 0;

    public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, String serverText) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.serverText = serverText;
        initCurrentPos();
        if (serialCom == null) {
             serialCom = new TwoWaySerialComm();
        }
        try {
            if (!serialCom.isConnected("COM5")) {
                try {
                    serialCom.connect("COM5");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mState = new MultiServoState(serialCom);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchPortException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            work();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }

    public void work() throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            InputStream input = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            outToClient = new DataOutputStream(output);
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            updateData();
            String message = null;
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000;
            while ((message = (String) inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {

                System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
                parse(message);

                sound_average = degrees[6];
                //
                // Send the positional data to the robot
                //
                mState.runServo(degrees[0], degrees[1], degrees[2],
                    degrees[3], degrees[4], degrees[5]);


                //
                // Send a response information to the client application
                //
                currentPos[0] = mState.getCurrentPos(0);
                currentPos[1] = mState.getCurrentPos(1);
                currentPos[2] = mState.getCurrentPos(2);
                currentPos[3] = mState.getCurrentPos(3);
                currentPos[4] = mState.getCurrentPos(4);
                try {
                    updateData();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Request processed: " + time);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // report exception somewhere
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

          /**
          * Initiate the robot's starting position.
          */
          public void initCurrentPos()
          {
              currentPos[0] = 100;
    currentPos[1] = 100;
    currentPos[2] = 100;
    currentPos[3] = 100;
    currentPos[4] = 100;
    currentPos[5] = 0;
          }

    /**
    * Send the data to the client
    * 
    * @throws IOException
    */
    public void updateData() throws IOException {
    String sentence = Integer.toString(currentPos[0]) + ", " + 
                      Integer.toString(currentPos[1]) + ", " +
                      Integer.toString(currentPos[2]) + ", " + 
                      Integer.toString(currentPos[3]) + ", " + 
                      Integer.toString(currentPos[4]) + "." + "\n";
        outToClient.flush();
        outToClient.writeBytes(sentence);
    }

    /**
     * Get the clients sound average
     * @param message
     */
    public int getSoundAverage() {
        return sound_average;
    }

    public void parse(String message) {
        if (message != null) {
            char c;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(4);
            int j = 0;
            boolean help = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
                c = message.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    sb.append(c);
                    help = true;
                }
                if (!Character.isDigit(c) && help == true) {
                    degrees[j] = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
                    j++;
                    help = false;
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Waiting for client message...");
    }

    /**
     * Close all connections
     */
    public void close() {
        if (connected) {
            synchronized (this) {
                connected = false;
            }
            if (outToClient != null) {
                try {
                    outToClient.close();
                    synchronized (this) {
                        outToClient = null;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // there is nothing we can do: ignore it
                }
            }

            if (inFromClient != null) {
                try {
                    inFromClient.close();
                    synchronized (this) {
                        inFromClient = null;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // there is nothing we can do: ignore it
                }
            }

            if (clientSocket != null) {
                try {
                    clientSocket.close();
                    synchronized (this) {
                        clientSocket = null;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // there is nothing we can do: ignore it
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void returnThread() {
        return;
    }
}
```

The final class is the thread handler where I try to compare sound levels and yield all threads except the loudest one:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import com.research.aserver.WorkerRunnable;


public class ThreadHandler implements Runnable {

    protected boolean   isStopped       = false;
    protected Thread        runningThread   = null;
    protected Thread        clientThread    = null;
    private Hashtable<Long, WorkerRunnable> Users = new Hashtable<Long, WorkerRunnable>();
    private ArrayList<Thread> ClientThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    private WorkerRunnable  client      = null;
    private int     sound_max       = 0;
    private int     index       = 0;

    public ThreadHandler() {
    }

    public void setUp(WorkerRunnable client, Thread clientThread) {
        this.client = client;
        this.clientThread = clientThread;
        Users.put(clientThread.getId(), this.client);   // Place clients in a list with its thread ID as key
        ClientThreads.add(this.clientThread);           // List of client threads
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000;       // Help variable to check every 2 sec
        while (!Users.isEmpty() && !ClientThreads.isEmpty()) {

            for (int i = 0; i < ClientThreads.size(); i++) {    // Remove clients and threads if no longer active
                if (!ClientThreads.get(i).isAlive()) {
                    Users.remove(ClientThreads.get(i).getId());
                    ClientThreads.get(i).interrupt();
                    ClientThreads.remove(i);
                }
            }
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() >= endTime) { // Do work every 2 sec
                for (int i = 0; i < ClientThreads.size(); i++) {    // Get the client with the loudest sound
                    if (sound_max < Users.get(ClientThreads.get(i).getId()).getSoundAverage()) {
                        sound_max = Users.get(ClientThreads.get(i).getId()).getSoundAverage();
                        index = i;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < ClientThreads.size(); i++) {    // yield all threads that are not the loudest
                    if (Users.get(ClientThreads.get(index).getId()) != Users.get(ClientThreads.get(i).getId())){
                        ClientThreads.get(i).yield();
                        index = 0;
                    }
                }
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000;                        // update time
            }
            sound_max = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What defines "appropriate" in your program?

Comment: Well aprorpiate in my program is just the thread which has the highest level sound. Because I thought that the person speaking should make the most noise when talking.

Comment: I added synchronization with locks and then it worked.
I lock all the other threads except one which does it's thing. Then it's done I lock that one as well and unlock the approrpiate thread.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Answer (score 0):

One idea might be to use a [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) and define a quality value for each input, which is then sort by quality automatically inside the list.

Using this your consumer thread can simply fetch the first one in line and process it, knowing that it is the most appropriate one, while the generator threads can simply throw all input in the Queue.